# c# Split string that contains letters and numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I need to split a string like this:

```
string mystring = "A2";
mystring[0] "A" 
mystring[1] "2" 

string mystring = "A11";
mystring[0] "A" 
mystring[1] "11" 

string mystring = "A111";
mystring[0] "A" 
mystring[1] "111" 

string mystring = "AB1";
mystring[0] "AB" 
mystring[1] "1"
```

My string always will be letter(s) than number(s), so I need to split it when letters finish. I need to use the number only in this case.

How I can do it? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex

```
var parts = Regex.Matches(yourstring, @"\D+|\d+")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex.Split will do it easily.

```
string input = "11A";
Regex regex = new Regex("([0-9]+)(.*)");
string[] substrings = regex.Split(input);
```

Comment: OP posted letters then numbers.  Upvoted for the best answer, but his code would need the reverse regex expression

Comment: Hi answer was right, I was editing it in the same time he replied. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regular expression to do this:

```
string[] output = Regex.Matches(mystring, "[0-9]+|[^0-9]+")
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(match => match.Value)
.ToArray();
```